# Splitting a 7 million row CSV by a specific column

Tags: windows-7, csv

How would I go about splitting a very large (7 million rows) CSV file into several different sheets/files by a specific numerical column. It should split into about 10 different files.

Comment: How exactly is the file split? Each column goes to a different file?

Comment: On what operating system, program, etc? (e.g. Windows + Excel, Linux + Libreoffice ...)

Comment: @CristianCiupitu I would like to split up the data based off 1 column. That 1 column has about 10 different values. So I wanna put each row with its respected column value into a seperate file. So it should come out to 10 different files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this [Python 3](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import binascii
import csv
import os.path
import sys
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
from tkinter.simpledialog import askinteger

def split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, keyfunc):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f)
    csv_writers = {}
    for row in csv_reader:
        k = keyfunc(row)
        if k not in csv_writers:
            csv_writers[k] = csv.writer(open(os.path.join(dst_dir, k),
                                             mode='w', newline=''))
        csv_writers[k].writerow(row)

def get_args_from_cli():
    input_filename = sys.argv[1]
    column = int(sys.argv[2])
    dst_dir = sys.argv[3]
    return (input_filename, column, dst_dir)

def get_args_from_gui():
    input_filename = askopenfilename(
        filetypes=(('CSV', '.csv'),),
        title='Select CSV Input File')
    column = askinteger('Choose Table Column', 'Table column')
    dst_dir = askdirectory(title='Select Destination Directory')
    return (input_filename, column, dst_dir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        input_filename, column, dst_dir = get_args_from_gui()
    elif len(sys.argv) == 4:
        input_filename, column, dst_dir = get_args_from_cli()
    else:
        raise Exception("Invalid number of arguments")
    with open(input_filename, mode='r', newline='') as f:
        split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, lambda r: r[column-1]+'.csv')
        # if the column has funky values resulting in invalid filenames
        # replace the line from above with:
        # split_csv_file(f, dst_dir, lambda r: binascii.b2a_hex(r[column-1].encode('utf-8')).decode('utf-8')+'.csv')
```

Save it as `split-csv.py` and run it from Explorer or from the command line.

For example to split `superuser.csv` based off column 1 and write the output files under `dstdir` use:

```
python split-csv.py superuser.csv 1 dstdir
```

If you run it without arguments, a Tkinter based GUI will prompt you to choose the input file, the column (1 based index) and the destination directory.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! Actually worked. I was about to resort to coding a script to get the job done, in Java. But woo!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. If I would have known you are a power user, I wouldn't have wasted time with the GUI :-) A vote along with the existing ✔ would be nice, too :-)

Comment: Noooo haha. I enjoyed the GUI very much haha. I did select yours as the answer but sadly since I just joined this community I need a bit more rep. I'm usually on the StackOverflow community haha. And hmm... For some reason after you write the row, it writes another row. Any suggestions? It's kinda annoying that every other row is blank.

Comment: I see. By the way in all fairness I voted the [awk answer](http://superuser.com/a/762465/2357). I don't understand the blank row thing. Maybe it has something to do with the line endings. Check the files with an editor (perhaps [vim](http://www.vim.org)).

Comment: @BrandonMXB, try again, I think I've fixed the issue.

Comment: Woot! Very much so. Great work. If I were you I'd sand off the sharp edges and clean it up and let more people know about it. I'm sure people will see it here on SE. Again, thanks a bunches!

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Happy to upvote you.... Good job...

Answer (score 5):

This could be as simple as this one-liner with `awk`:

```
awk -F ',' '{ print > ("split-" $1 ".csv") }' 7mil.csv
```

- The input file here is `7mil.csv`
- The deciding column number is indicated with the dollar sign. If it was the third column, it would be `$3` instead of `$1`
- The column value is used to generate the resulting file name. So for example, every line with the value `42` will be in a file named `split-42.csv`
- The field separator is the comma

  - which works because/if the value is numeric, and doesn't have any quotes that need to be stripped
  - but also requires that there are no commas in any strings in the file (at least not before the numeric column)

So this just reads every line and prints it to the file that corresponds to the value. Note that it adds to the file, so if you run it twice, all the data will be duplicated; so make sure there are no files with that naming pattern to start: `del split-*.cvs`

The hard part for trying this is installing `awk` on Windows. There's [gawk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) and a [few tips for running it here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21927944/how-to-run-an-awk-commands-in-windows).

Comment: I'm sure this would have worked too but I saw the solution above first. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Ken: Your answer is very much appreciated! This one-liner was just what I needed for a data pipeline on a Linux system :)

Answer (score 1):

[Delimit](http://delimitware.com/) can do that. It opens very fast large csv files ("up to 2 billion rows and 2 million columns large!"). Use split vertically and/or choose your columns.

Another software that may be able to do it is [Emeditor](http://www.emeditor.com/emeditor-core/next-version-emeditor-will-enhance-csv-support/).